# Salesforce Customer

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-service-cloud, salesforce-chatter

•   Create a Custom Field on the Standard Object called “Accounts” on the setup menu
•   Add the following custom filed
Field Name  Datatype    Constraint
Priority    Picklist (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)

•   Create a Custom Object called “Customer” on the setup menu
•   Add the following custom fields
Field Name  Datatype    Constraint
Title   Picklist (Mr, Mrs, Miss)
First_Name  Text(100)   Required
Last_Name   Text(100)   Required
Age Number
Address Text(255)
Gender  Picklist(Male, Female)
Ref. Account    Lookup(Account)

•   Create a new Trigger class based on the newly created Custom Object “Customer” to handle duplicate Customer Records.
•   Trigger should handle bulk operations as well
•   Business requirement as follows:
o   Trigger should handle both Insert and Update operations on “Customer”
o   Title, First_Name, Last_Name combination must be unique
o   At any given time, there should be only unique records in the system
o   If a duplicate record found, latest record should be in the system while the previous should get deleted
o   If the latest Customer record has a “Ref. Account” with lesser priority than the duplicate found record; change the “Ref. Account” of the latest Customer record to the higher priority account if found on the duplicate record. Always the latest customer record should have the highest priority account with respective to its duplicate. (Note: Priority 1 is the min, Priority 5 is the max)

Please try to provide Answer for this in Salesforce solution as soon as possible. Please advice how to delete and add new record in triggers.

Comment: do you have something specific you'd like to ask? what did you try so far to do and where did you get stuck?

Comment: I have done up to handle duplicate records and delete duplicate records.

Answer (score 0):

I have done up to handle duplicate records and delete duplicate records.I stuck with get Ref.Account with lesser priority account. how to access Account object priority field and compare with current record Account Priority field? Please reply as soon as possible.

```
trigger CustomerTigger on Customer__c(Before insert, Before update) {
    List < Customer__c > StaActiList = [Select ID, First_Name__c, Last_Name__c, Title__c, Address__c, Gender__c, RefAccount__c
    from Customer__c];
    for (Customer__c opp: Trigger.new) {
        for (Customer__c sa: StaActiList) {
            try {

                if (sa.First_Name__c == opp.First_Name__c && sa.Last_Name__c == opp.Last_Name__c && sa.Title__c == opp.Title__c) {
                    List < Id > lstId = new List < Id > ();
                    List < Customer__c > existoppList = [Select Id from Customer__c where Id = : sa.Id];
                    delete existoppList;
                }

            } catch (Exception Ex) {

            }
        }
    }
}
```